# Rails 3, devise, how can I send the confirmation email even if devise is not set to confirmable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Maybe this is simple and I haven't figured it out yet, but I want to send the confirmation email that is created when you run the devise views command.

I am running the following model method:

```
def send_invitation
     User.find(self).send_confirmation_instructions
   end
```

but when I run this I get

```
undefined method `send_confirmation_instructions'
```

there is a mailer in views/devise/mailer/confirm_instructions.html.erb

Is there a way to send that email without setting users to confirmable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the points at which you do/don't want the confirmation feature, but you could include Confirmable but override the methods for the Confirmable features you don't want. Or you could call `User.skip_confirmation!` after users are created, which automatically "confirms" the user, bypassing Confirmable when you don't want it.